# Identification for ticket collection

Tags: usa, tickets, paperwork, buses

I have a friend who is stuck in Marble Falls TX. She was riding with another friend who went to jail and she was left with no ride home, but she left her purse at home in Livingston TX which contained her ID.

Can I purchase her a ticket and her be able to get on bus without her ID?

Comment: Check the specific conditions of the bus ticket you want to buy.

Comment: Because it has to be said: do double-check this is truly your friend, not a scammer.

Comment: @MatthieuM. this being the US, they could verify at least the part about the friend going to jail; https://texas.staterecords.org/inmate see section "How to Perform a Texas Jail Inmate Search"

Comment: I know Texas is big (Texans keep telling us just how big it is!), but have you considered going to pick up the friend in person? Might be nice to get out of the house and take a drive.

Comment: @FreeMan:  For the record, Marble Falls to Livingston is 4.5 hours one way, so that'd be a nine hour round-trip assuming the OP is also in Livingston.  (As you note, Texas is big.)  And, of course, we don't know for sure that the OP has a car of their own.

Comment: Acknowledged, @MichaelSeifert. Just tossing out another possibility. Sometimes, people don't see the forest for the trees...

Answer (score 28):

The [Greyhound website](https://www.greyhound.com/en/help-and-info/ticket-info/cardholder-not-traveling) says about remote purchasing of tickets:

> **Prepaid Ticket Orders (PTO)**
>
> A non-refundable $18 Prepaid Ticket Order fee will be applied at the time of purchase. This fee is per transaction, not per ticket, so it's the same no matter how many tickets you buy.  The Prepaid Ticket is available for immediate use and can be picked up at the bus station they’ll be traveling from.  PTO’s are only applicable at US Greyhound locations.
>
> To pick up their tickets at the station, the person traveling will need to provide:
>
> - Photo ID **or** password chosen by the person purchasing the ticket
> - Confirmation Number

So it looks as though the ticket can be picked up without ID, if they know the password and confirmation number.

Presumably this is to cover a situation such as yours.

Comment: Of note: this procedure for a Prepaid Ticket Order and $18 fee only applies if the purchaser is buying the ticket *at a station*. If the purchaser is buying online, the Gift Ticket Order procedure applies and there's no fee.